# Dynamics AX Unusual Table Behavior

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

It's apparently the week for unusual AX problems.  I have custom, company-independent tables in AX that on first view always shows one particular record.  This occurs if you access them from a form, view the tables directly, etc.

Open a form using one of the malfunctioning tables as a datasource and you only see one record.

Open a table directly (CTRL-O), and you only see that one record.  However, if you hit the green arrow to re-execute the SQL query, the rest of the records appear.

I've tried dropping and reimporting the tables, adjusting the indices, deleting a variety of record combinations, but nothing has any effect.  If I delete the one row that appears, another one replaces it as the one appearing record.  Add that row back in (new RecId, same data) and that row resumes its original position.

I exported these tables from another system where they were working perfectly.  I also imported the exact same structure to another instance on the same Dynamics server, and everything works perfectly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure you're running the client on the same version as your application? Check to see if your Kernel version matches the Application.

Comment: Kernal: 5.0.1500.4570    Application: 5.0.1000.52    I guess the next question is, how do I sync those up?  RU7 brought the Kernal up, but apparently, the client (on the same machine) didn't come up with it.

Comment: So your client is RU7, but the application itself is a bare SP1 with no Rollups. There is a dependecy break between RU3 and 4 where grids would only load the first row from each table. I think this is what is troubling you. You should make sure your client and server is on same version, at least when developing. :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue and cause.  That helped a lot.